# Insert performance - Oracle vs Postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql, performance-testing, database-performance

I found this scenario; In oracle I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE" 
(   
"COL1" NUMBER, 
"COL2" DATE, 
"COL3" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
"COL4" NUMBER, 
....
"COL34" VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)
);
CREATE INDEX "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE_INDEX3" ON "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE" ("COL4") 
CREATE INDEX "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE_INDEX4" ON "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE" ("COL10") 
CREATE INDEX "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE_INDEX5" ON "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE" ("COL1") 
CREATE INDEX "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE_INDEX6" ON "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE" ("COL20") 
CREATE INDEX "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE_INDEX1" ON "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE" ("COL3") 
CREATE INDEX "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE_INDEX2" ON "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE" ("COL5") 

CREATE TABLE MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE_AUX AS (SELECT * FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE);
```

I replicated the same table for postgres; as you can see, mytable_aux has no indexes.

In oracle, this query takes 157 seconds:

```
--table mytable count=0 rows
--table mytable_aux=8.289.678 rows
insert into MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE(select * from MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE_AUX); --175 seg
```

In postgres, with even less records, takes longer than 10 minutes

```
--table mytable count=0 rows
--table mytable_aux=3.557.365 rows
insert into myschema.mytable (select * from myschema.mytable_aux ); --10 minutes
```

Rest assured that the tables from the two db engines are equivalent and they manage the same records. Is there something I'm missing? how can I improve the postgres performance?

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges. Oracle and Postgres function differently. They might be on two different servers, with different CPUs and memory available. Tablespaces might be different. Caching is different. You'll have different competing processes running other queries. Row-level locking may be different. Postgres and Oracle are going to have their own settings. You may want to edit the question to focus on your Postgres setup and leave out all the Oracle stuff. I'd also recommend posting in dba.stackexchange.com, as you may get a better response there about performance questions.

Comment: Why does my Ferrari have a v_max larger than my Lamborghini? Oh wait, I didn't tell you the exact models. In fact my Lamborghini is actually a classic [tractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamborghini_Trattori), pulling some loaded trailers up hill. And my Ferrari is one of their formula one cars on a straight section of a race track driven by one of the finest, fueled with some carefully composed, special mixture of combustibles... You get the point.

Comment: The question does not contain enough information to help you. 10 Minutes to insert 3 million rows is definitely too slow, but without more information this is nearly impossible to answer. Are both statements done on the same hardware? Were other things running on the server? What exactly is stored in the columns you have not shown us? It makes a difference if those are all integers or all `bytea` columns with hundreds of megabytes

Comment: On my desktop computer (regular harddisk, no SSD), inserting 8 million rows takes less than 3 minutes: https://imgur.com/a/BAS04bD

Answer (score 0):

Provided that all the comments above are correct, and you should analyze the problem with a postgresql dba, you can try to tune the work_mem parameter at session level:

```
SET work_mem to '1MB';

INSERT INTO myschema.mytable SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable_aux;

SET work_mem to '10MB';

INSERT INTO myschema.mytable SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable_aux;
```

You also might try to disable/enable table logging, if it works!
You can also try to use the append hint inserting your rows, if it works!
It's not clear which postgresql you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I would check what kind of disk each server is using - if you are on AWS, EBS would be faster than EFS, in a server, a local SSD is faster than spinning disk or NFS, and so on.